# Haskell variable not in scope terminal

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I have download Haskell via terminal and using VSCode for editor but it doesn't work [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXhDM.png)

[VScode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOuws.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you are loading the code into GHCi.

If you load it using `:l` *filename.hs* or `:r`, GHCi always makes the functions available. Does your file load without error?

If you load it using `:m` *Module* you need to explicitly export the functions, otherwise they are private to the module.

I also notice that you are not using Haskell Language Server (HLS) in your Visual Studio Code, and you are not declaring the types of your functions. Both decisions may bite you hard. To get HLS please install extension 'Haskell'.

Comment: ı have loaded by using :l and it didn't error .        [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( trying.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.    Like this.Also there is a HLS in my VSCode that is the real problem actually for me.Why it is not working even if with HLS.Thanks for answer by the way :)

Comment: Which operating system are you using? I have used HLS on Windows without problems, but with Linux Mint I had to update the operating system to deal with the problem.

Comment: My problems and solution for HLS on Mint Linux: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/xrfoze/problems_with_hls_vscode_on_mint_linux/